# DBFlow using JSONModel throws InvalidDBconfiguration: JSONModel is not registered with a Database

Tags: android, orm

I'm starting to use DBFlow and following the documentation. I have a huge JSON and I don't wanna upload all in memory so I'm using JSONModel approach that they've implemented.

```
    admissionJSONModel = new JSONModel<Admission>(jsonObject, Admission.class);
```

The admission class:

```
@Table(databaseName = AppDatabase.NAME)
@ContainerAdapter
public class Admission extends BaseModel {

  /**
   * Ticket Reference (barcode number)
   */
  @NonNull
  @ContainerKey("TICKET_REF")
  @Column(columnType = Column.PRIMARY_KEY)
  String mTicketReference;

  @NonNull
  @Column
  @ContainerKey("FIRST_NAME")
  String mFirstName;

  /**
   * Ticket type (related to Record type)
   * In ADDRESS_CITY
   */
  @Column
  @ContainerKey("TICKET_TYPE")
  int mTicketType;


                ...
}
```

Ant the database class:

```
@Database(name = AppDatabase.NAME, version = AppDatabase.VERSION, foreignKeysSupported = true)
public class AppDatabase {

    public static final String NAME = "App";

    public static final int VERSION = 1;
}
```

The stack trace of the exception that I have is:

```
Process: com.glownet.app.staging.debug, PID: 19083
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.InvalidDBConfiguration: Table: com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.container.JSONModel is not registered with a Database. Did you forget the @Table annotation?
            at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.runtime.DBTransactionQueue.run(DBTransactionQueue.java:77)
     Caused by: com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.InvalidDBConfiguration: Table: com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.container.JSONModel is not registered with a Database. Did you forget the @Table annotation?
            at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.FlowManager.getDatabaseForTable(FlowManager.java:63)
            at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.runtime.transaction.process.ProcessModelHelper.process(ProcessModelHelper.java:26)
            at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.runtime.transaction.process.ProcessModelTransaction.onExecute(ProcessModelTransaction.java:34)
            at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.runtime.transaction.process.ProcessModelTransaction.onExecute(ProcessModelTransaction.java:12)
            at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.runtime.DBTransactionQueue.run(DBTransactionQueue.java:63)
```

Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the author,
If you are using a `ProcessModelTransaction`, you should change the code to save the `JSONModel` to the DB like this:

`TransactionManager.getInstance().addTransaction(new ProcessModelTransaction<>(ProcessModelInfo.withModels(models).table(Admission.class);`

currently this is a bug where the method `table()` does not exist. So what happens is it thinks that the JSONModels are a table (since they implement model), but are just shell, blueprint classes of real models.

Thank you for finding this. if you can open an issue on github, I can mark you as a contributor. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Now, since version 1.6.1, it now detects the models are `ModelContainer` and will grab the appropriate table to use.